# Python numbering paragraph from a txt file

Tags: python

I need to read a .txt file and number the paragraphs this is the desired output:

**0** --------------- blank space

**00)** paragraph 1 line 1

**01)** paragraph 1 line 2

**1** --------------- blank space

**10)** paragraph 2 line 1

**2** ---------------blank space

**20)** paragraph 3 line 1

**21)** paragraph 3 line 2

I made this:
`for count, val in enumerate(sentenceList): print("{}) {}.".format(count, val))`

but the output of my code is:

0 ------------

0 ) paragraph one line 1

1 ) paragraph one line 2

1 ------------

0 ) paragraph 3 line 1

2 ------------

0 ) paragraph 4 line 1

1 )  paragraph 4 line 2

Comment: You need to include the paragraph number in there: `print("{}{}) {}.".format(para,count,val)`.

Answer (score 1):

#### par.txt

```
par1 line1
par1 line2

par2 line1

par3 line1
par3 line2
```

#### code

```py
blank_space_cnt = 0
line_cnt = 0

with open('par.txt') as f:
    for lines in f:
        if lines == "\n":
            print(f'{blank_space_cnt} -------- blank space')
            blank_space_cnt += 1
            line_cnt = 0
        else:
            print(f'{blank_space_cnt-1}{line_cnt}) paragraph {blank_space_cnt} line {line_cnt+1}')
            line_cnt += 1
```

#### output

```
0 -------- blank space
00) paragraph 1 line 1
01) paragraph 1 line 2
1 -------- blank space
10) paragraph 2 line 1
2 -------- blank space
20) paragraph 3 line 1
21) paragraph 3 line 2
```